# How does the new async/await feature in C# 5 integrate with the message loop?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-ctp, async-await

I've not had chance to check out the CTP of the new C# async/await feature, but here's something I was wondering:

How does it integrate with the message loop? I assume that in a standard Windows application (Winforms, WPF) the continuations are called by sending messages to the application's message loop, using a [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) or similar?

What if I'm not using a standard windows message loop? For example in a GTK# application or in  a console application (if indeed this feature could be of use at all in a console application).

I've searched the internet for information about this but to no avail. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.  Both WPF and Winforms install their own version of SynchronizationContext.  Which use their message loop to marshal the call from a worker thread back to the main UI thread.  Respectively with Dispatcher.Begin/Invoke and Control.Begin/Invoke().

Getting this done in a Console mode app is not easy, its main thread doesn't have a well defined 'idle' state that would allow injecting marshaled method calls in a safe manner that avoids re-entrancy headaches.  You could certainly add it but you'll be re-inventing the message loop doing so.

Comment: Thanks Hank. Trying to think of a situation where async would be of use in a console application and failing. So I think the lack of a synchronization context in this situation is mostly moot.

Comment: [AsyncEx](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) includes an [AsyncContext](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext) class which provides an async-compatible main loop for Console apps (and unit tests).

Comment: More about `SynchronizationContext` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It all comes down to what the "awaiter" does with the continuation it's passed.

The implementation for `Task<T>` in the BCL will use the current synchronization context ([unless you ask it not to using `ConfigureAwait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456403.aspx)) - which means in WPF/SilverLight it'll use the dispatcher; in Windows Forms it'll use something like `Control.BeginInvoke`, and in a thread-pool thread it'll just keep run on any thread pool thread. Note that it's your current context *at the point of the await expression* which is important, as that's what the task will capture for the continuation to run on.

The linked blog post (by Mads Torgersen) does a great job of explaining how it all works under the hood, and I have a [series of blog posts](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/eduasync/) which you may find useful too.

Comment: Thanks Jon. In all my excursions in .Net land I've never come across SynchronizationContext.Current, which is what I assume you mean by the "current synchronization context"? Learn something new every day.

Comment: @Groky: Yes. There's more in Stephen Toub's article about performance with async: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx